Websockets using SSL: SSL_R_NO_SHARED_CIPHER
I've setup a simple PHP websocket server using Ratchet (in Symfony) like this:
        $server = new TcpServer('0.0.0.0:3001');
        $server = new SecureServer($server, null, [
            'local_cert' => '/home/xxx/location/fullchain14.pem',
            'local_pk' => '/home/xxx/location/privkey14.pem',
        ]);
        $server->on('connection', function (SocketConnectionInterface $connection) {
            echo 'Secure connection from '.$connection->getRemoteAddress().PHP_EOL;

            $connection->write('Hi this is a test message!');
        });
        $server->on('error', function (\Exception $e) {
            echo 'Error: '.$e->getMessage().PHP_EOL;
        });

I connect to it using javascript with the following code:
let ws = new WebSocket('wss://develop.xxxx.com:3001');
ws.onopen = function() {
 console.log("Connected!");
 ws.send("hello!");
 console.log("Message is sent...");
};

The certificates are in the correct location (symfony root dir, just to test for now) and I've set the permissions to 755. I got them from LetsEncrypt and they work fine with Apache. I'm already using the HTTPS version of the website (http is disabled) and the certificates are fine.
When I run my server and go to my webpage with the websocket javascript, this is the output of the server:
$ php bin/console websocket:start
Starting server on port 3001
Waiting for connections...
Error: Connection from tcp://xx.xx.xx.xx:57363 failed during TLS handshake: SSL_R_NO_SHARED_CIPHER: no suitable shared cipher could be used.  This could be because the server is missing an SSL certificate (local_cert context option)

Obviously I am using a local_cert, and I'm pretty sure I am using the correct LetsEncrypt files (I also have a "cert.pem" file and a "chain.pem")
What am I doing wrong here? I'm using OpenSSL 3.0.2 if that is relevant.
